# How to reorder the columns of created (calculated) table in data view in power bi?

Tags: powerbi

As the title said, I created a table by CALCULATETABLE function in power bi and then calculated some new columns. So, how to reorder the columns now?

As the title said, I created a table by CALCULATETABLE function in power bi and then calculated some new columns. So, how to reorder the columns now?

Comment: Why would you want to reorder the columns? What difference does that make?

Answer (score 0):

Use [SELECTCOLUMNS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/selectcolumns-function-dax) after CALCULATETABLE to change the columns.

Comment: Actually, I mean how to reorder the columns after the table has been set. For example, to position the new column into a certain place when adding a new column